# Beginner in JS and as3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I have no experience with javascript and hence this silly question... I don't know what's wrong with this code... may be its the scope of the two variables.. but i am not able to retrieve the values of the variables in the function... please help.

```
function fetchFBData (userId)
    {
        //console.log (userId);

        var picurl;
        var playername;

        FB.api('/'+userId+'/picture?width=50&height=50', picResponse);
        FB.api('/'+userId, nameResponse);

        function picResponse (response)
        {
            picurl = response.data.url;
            console.log(picurl);
        }

        function nameResponse (response)
        {
            playername = response.name;
            console.log (playername);
        }

        document.getElementById("demo1").playerData(playername, picurl);            
    }
```

Comment: And yes.. i am calling this function from my as3 code... and the element "demo1" is a swf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`picResponse` and `nameResponse` are called asynchronously that means you are calling the `playerData` function when the `picurl` and `playername` are not set yet. You need to wait for both of those functions to complete before calling `playerData`. Something like :

```
function fetchFBData (userId)
{
    var picurl;
    var playername;

    FB.api('/'+userId+'/picture?width=50&height=50', picResponse);

    function picResponse (response)
    {
        picurl = response.data.url;
        FB.api('/'+userId, nameResponse);
    }

    function nameResponse (response)
    {
        playername = response.name;
        document.getElementById("demo1").playerData(playername, picurl);            
    }
}
```

Comment: ok fine... thats working... :)

and its not the 'scope' problem... :P